# finding a function given a complicated relation involving integrals

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

> Find a function $g$ continuous in $[0,\infty]$ and positive in $(0,\infty)$ satisfying $g(0)=1$ and
> $$ \tag{1}
> \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x} g^2(t)dt=\frac{1}{x}f^2(x),
> $$
> where $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$.

My try:clearly $f'(x)=g(x)$

differentiating  original condition we get

$$4f(x)g(x)=xg^2(x)+\int_{0}^{x}g^2(t)dt$$

using (1)

$$4f(x)g(x)=xg^2(x)+\frac{2}{x}f^2(x)$$

now i am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing the relation by $x$ and writing $f$ explicitly, we have that
$$
\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x g^2 = \left(\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x g\right)^2,
\qquad \forall x > 0.
$$
Passing to the limit as $x\to 0^+$ and taking into account that $g(0) = 1$ we thus obtain that $1/2 = 1$, a contradiction.

Hence, there is no such $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your last line, multiply both sides by x
$$4xf(x)g(x)=x^2g^2(x)+2f^2(x)$$
move all in one side
$$ {x^2}g{(x)^2} - 4xf(x)g\left( x \right) + 2f{(x)^2} = 0$$
solve for $g(x)$
$$g(x) = \frac{{f(x)\left( {2 \pm \sqrt 2 } \right)}}{x} $$
remember that $f'\left( x \right) = g\left( x \right)$
$$f'(x) = \frac{{f(x)\left( {2 \pm \sqrt 2 } \right)}}{x}$$
and then
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{ {2 \pm \sqrt 2 }}{x}$$
integrate both sides
$$\log f(x)=\left( {2 \pm \sqrt 2 } \right)\log x+C$$
$$f(x)= kx^{ {2 \pm \sqrt 2 }}$$
and finally
$$g(x)=k\left( {2 \pm \sqrt 2 } \right)x^{ {1 \pm \sqrt 2 }}$$
This function doesn't satisfy the condition $g(0)=1$, so there is no solution.